# Write a Bash script that determines the users logged in and produces structured output

Tags: linux

I need to write a bash program "getuserinfo" that determines the users that are logged in to a system and produces output like the following:

Name: Paul Beliveau      userID: csi2300100      start: 17:05 2013-09-17
Name: Bob Dangelo        userID: csi2300133      start: 09:12 2013-09-16
Name: David Pease        userID: csi2300141      start: 11:34 2013-09-17
Name: Lee Patrick        userID: csi2300148      start: 14:29 2013-09-17

Curently all I have is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

for person in $(who | cut -f1)
do
    ID=$person
    name=grep $ID /etc/passwd | cut -d':' -f5 #causes error
    start=      #Not sure what to do here

    echo "Name: $name userID: $ID start: $start"

done

exit 0
```

I know this is far from correct, but all i have been able to do succesfully so far is find a way to loop through the users in the system by their userID. My plan was to store values in variables name, userID, and start and then print them for each run through the loop. My current problem is getting the name as a variable, and finding a way to cut the start time out of the who command.

Comment: You do know that the `w` command basically does what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few problems I see with your current approach:

1. If you want to assign a variable to the output of a command, you need to use `$(..)` or else backticks ``` `` ```.  For example:

   ```
   name="$(grep $ID /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5)"
   ```
2. Be careful with your `grep` and `cut` combo in your `name=` assignment though.  What happens if the user's login name is a substring in another user's login name?  What if one user's login name is contained in another user's actual name.  Consider using regular expressions to narrow this down a bit.  Maybe something like this (but I'll bet you can do better):

   ```
   name="$(grep "^${ID}:" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f5)"
   ```
3. I would recommend using the `getent` command instead of `/etc/passwd`.  `getent` will give you the login information you seek even if it is not in a local file.  For example, if you are using NIS or LDAP.

   ```
   name="$(getent passwd | grep "^${ID}:" | cut -d: -f5)"
   ```
4. Consider keeping the entire output of the `who` command and reading it line-by-line.  You can then pull out their login name and login time.  Something like:

   ```
   who | while read whoent
   do
     ID="$(echo $whoent | cut -d' ' -f1)"
     start="$(echo $whoent | cut-d' ' -f3,4)"
   ```

Good luck!

Comment: Wow. This is seems much more simple.. I guess I was fixed on using a for loop to solve it. I also didn't realize you could pipe who and while like that.   This is extremely helpful,  Thank you !